# Mocha, Chai, Sinon test error in multiple files

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have multiple files to test, all these files are using the same custom `../tools/http.util.js` library like this:

```
const HttpUtil = require('../libs/http.util');
```

So, I'm mocking this library in each file with this code:

```
before('before', function () {
    let HttpUtilMock = sinon.stub();
    HttpUtilMock.prototype.formGetUri = sinon.stub().returns("http://mock.com/");
    HttpUtilMock.prototype.formBaseRequestHeader = sinon.stub().returns("headers");
    testFunction.__set__("HttpUtil", HttpUtilMock);
});
```

When I run `mocha test/ --recursive --timeout=3000`, I get the **problem**: `http.util` file is mocked in the first test file, but it is not mocking in the second file - I get errors from the `http.util` while starting the second file test.

I assume, that I have to clear test data after completing the first file tests, but I couldn't find any clear commands for sinon, to clear the variable mock.

Comment: where does testFunction.__set__ come from?

Comment: @bhoo-day it's a part from rewire module - an option to test private functions, or set private variables

Answer (score 0):

To clear a sinon mock you use the restore method myMock.restore();

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that I'm thinking of instead of using `rewire` module.

```
....
const sinon = require('sinon');
let sandbox;

before('before', function () {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    sandbox.stub(HttpUtil, 'formGetUri').returns('http://mock.com');
    sandbox.stub(HttpUtil, 'formBaseRequestHeader').returns('headers');    
});

after('after', function() {
  sandbox.restore();
});
```

must call `restore()` after tests finished.